# What is the c++ standard ( non-windows) equivalent of Fuction SetFilePointer()

Tags: c++, function, standards, equivalent

I have a function using [`SetFilePointer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer)

```
HANDLE In;
SetFilePointer(In, 3, NULL, 0);
```

I want to adapt this function for non-windows platforms **taking a Pointer to FILE** (FILE*) as argument .

**What function Set_File_Pointer_SomeHow() does the same as SetFilePointer() which can I use for that?**

```
FILE* In;    
Set_File_Pointer_SomeHow(In,      );
```

Comment: [`fseek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fseek)?

Comment: what you seek is how to seek in a file.

Comment: Note that `FILE*` and the related APIs are part of the C standard library, not the C++ standard library. They're included in C++ as it's backwards compatible with C.

Comment: seekg Please read here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream and here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg

Answer (score 1):

I think you want [`std::fseek(std::FILE* stream, long offset, int origin)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fseek).